# Ubuntu 16.04 desktop right/left click does not work

Tags: dual-boot, unity, uefi

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS 64-bit alongside Windows 10 which had a bootloader in EFI partition together with secure boot enabled. However, I noticed that after using Ubuntu for some time (due to reasons I cannot pinpoint exactly) the left and right click buttons do not work on the desktop.

Note that they remain functional inside browsers and other programs. I use the default Unity desktop environment shipped with Ubuntu. The problem is not resolved without a restart or logout.

Comment: Have you ever installed the GNOME DE?

Comment: @heynnema No I am familiar with the Unity DE.

Comment: I asked because installing the GNOME DE would give similar symptoms.